# SwiftUI when dismissing a sheet the view behind it is unresponsive for a few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When dismissing a `.sheet` view in SwiftUI the view behind it is unresponsive for a second.

During my investigation of this bug I found that the Presentation Controller of the sheet is backed by a `UITransitionView`, which doesn't dismiss as fast as the sheet itself and is therefore blocking the taps. The problem is that this `UITransitionView` isn't a accessible in SwiftUI and this makes configuring the transition impossible in a way where I could prevent `UITransitionView` from blocking the view hierarchy.

Here is a minimal example on how to reproduce this behavior:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Show the sheeet").onTapGesture(perform: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet, content: {
            VStack {
                Button("Dismiss Sheet", action: {
                    self.showSheet.toggle()
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

After dismissing the sheet the view isn't responsive for ~1 second.

So is there a way to prevent this or do I have to right my own custom sheet?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7. If something works unexpected it is better to describe used environment from start.

Comment: Works fine on iOS 14 as well. Your tap gesture is only on the Text (make sure you're clicking the Text and not somewhere else on the screen).

Comment: I can confirm that we also have this issue. It seems to be "by design", I've noticed the same thing on Apple's new Translate app that came out on iOS 14, built with SwiftUI. When switching languages, they use a sheet animation and has the same issues (the button to pick a language is not responsive for ~1sec after dismissing the sheet).
We're also looking into building our own sheet, as we haven't found a way around it.